# How to style crispy forms with bootstrap4 in django?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to style upload form used from crispy forms. Can you give me simple solution, and not to get too crazy about css.

This is how it looks now!

[image]

This is upload_document.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

      <h1>Upload</h1>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
      </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class UploadFile(models.Model):
    excel = models.FileField(upload_to="excel/", max_length=250)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from .models import UploadFile

class GlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile
        fields = ('excel',)
```

I'm going for something like this!

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this `{{ form|crispy }}` ?

Comment: Just change an order, not quite what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1):

You should add
`CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'` to settings file, and also write
`{{ form|crispy }}` where you use form